# Increase space between two rows in one section

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to increase the space between two rows in one section? Table view style is grouped. There is one section, in that two rows are there. I need to increase the gap between these two rows. How to make this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You can use

```
<tr style="height:10px"><td></td></tr>
```

Don't put anything inside

Comment: It's poor style to use empty HTML tags instead of using CSS to style the existing content. I recommend using CSS to add appropriate padding to the actual `tr` elements.

Comment: better to use for all tr elements like tr{..}